# Import data file from folder image to excel columns using C#

Tags: c#

I have a folder with several images. I would like to import the name of the image on the first column using C#

it is possible to do so ? i have too many images to work with. thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

If you're willing to compromise and use a CSV file (comma seperated value), which opens natively in excel, it's very easy to do.

You need to get all the file names, like this :

```
string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles("c:\\images");
string[] fileNames = filePaths.Select(f => Path.GetFileName(f)).ToArray();
```

Then, format the result in a CSV style - seperate columns by commas (,) and lines by a line ending (on windows, it's "\r\n"). Because we only have one column, all we have to do is generate a long string, where the file names are seperated by line endings.

```
string csv = string.Join("\r\n", fileNames);
```

Then, save the result to a file - you can open this file directly in excel :

```
File.WriteAllText("result.csv",csv);
```

If you want to have more columns, just format each line with the columns seperated by commas.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using this library called "[EPPlus](http://epplus.codeplex.com/)" to create native .XLS and .XLSX files.

Get the image file names into some enumerable type:

```
string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles("c:\\images");
```

And the just do a simple loop over that array to set the values. Example loop body:

```
worksheet.Cells["A1"].Value = filePaths[0];
```